# Find out who I was before I had switched users in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, user-accounts

```
$ whoami
a

$ su b
Password: ...

$ whoami
b
```

Is there a `whowasi` command? Some way to find out that I was user `a` before I had become user `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Technically, you didn't *switch* users; you opened a separate shell process as `b`. You can suspend it with **`suspend`**, use **`whoami`**, then return with **`fg`**.
- You can check the owner of the parent process with **`ps -f $PPID`**.
- Use **`who -m` or `who am i`** to see the user you originally *logged in as.* (This is different from the above two methods because it always returns the same user despite how many times you run `su`.)
- Use **`ps -f`** to see all processes running on the current tty, including their owners.

Comment: The `who am i` is exactly what I want. I hadn't realized it returns a different answer from `whoami`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `who` to see what user is the original owner of the session